# How To Convert a Bitmap to a Collection of Paths in WPF (in code not XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, path, shapes, writeablebitmap

I have an occupancy grid that has 3 states - Occupied, Free, Unknown.  Occupancy grid is a simple 2 dimensional array of states.  The grid represents a floor plan where Occupied=Wall, Free=Open Floor, Unknown=what's behind the wall or not mapped.  This grid is say 800x800 wide with each cell representing 5cm of the real world.

I want to take this and make it into a WPF Path Shape.  Then I can then manipulate on the screen, Allow a user to add walls (by drawing lines), and eventually export to some form of CAD standard/SVG/etc.

I started playing with writable bitmaps and can create a perfect picture of the grid, how ever a bitmp isn't a path, and some of my lines are jagged or unconnected.

I am looking for ideas on how to translate this grid, or thebitmap, into clean wpf shapes.  Lines, Polygons, Polylines, or Paths would all make me very happy becuase once I have those I can do anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you upload a sample image?

Comment: Sample image of what I am working with - http://www.xehran.com/floorsample.png  Black is unknown space, white is wall space, blue is free (floor) space.  This is a bitmap rendered from my grid that has the same data

Comment: That image looks very familiar to me :) What sensor is that? Robot or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If your walls are only in some basic geometrical shapes (lines, others like circles get much more complicated) you might want to use [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) or some other transform, depending how your images look like. If I understand it correctly that your images have only three colours you might not have to use some edge detection algorithm.

Edit: If the Occupied state represents only thin surfaces of walls that is all you need. You would get lines for your walls (delimiting free/unknown areas)

Comment: good pointers - but once I have the edges detected and shapened how do you advise I translate those into a line/polyline/path?

Comment: After Hough (or similar) transform you get points (in transformed space) representing lines that are found in your image (even if you supply just some coordinates, not a real image (that should be even faster)).   After this you compare those lines to your map data to determine their length. This gives you a set of lines covering your walls. If you take their intersections (set of points) you should be able to create a polyline, polygon or whatever else you need. I am just before starting a real programming (not just drawing and thinking) work on something very similar - any experience welcome

Comment: I am first trying to vectorize the bitmap and see if that gets me what I want.  There are some edge detection functs in the library I am using (Potrace - well .net port of Potrace).  I think if i get  an svg I can then translate that to a path/poly and I am a happy guy.  I will update with progress

Comment: Potrace is giving me some really good results.  Feel from to contact me directly if you want some pointers.  Hough Transform got me no where!